# How can I use .net functions/classes to/from clojure-clr?

Tags: clojure, clojureclr

For example, how can I use `System.Console.WriteLine` from clojure-clr? In general, what's the rule for exporting/importing functions/classes from other languages such as C#/F# from/to Clojure-clr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Console is loaded by default. You can simply use:

```
(System.Console/WriteLine "Hello World!")
```

Another example, using a static class:

```
(import (System.IO Path))
(println (Path/GetFullPath "."))
```

Comment: is it different from the Java type? or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference, although I haven't looked into detail.

Answer (score 0):

in Java, instantiating the *Date* object, then calls its *toString()* method, you have to write like the following,

```
user=> (. (new java.util.Date) (toString))
```

Comment: While this example works, note that it can also be written as `(. (new java.util.Date) toString)` or `(.toString (new java.util.Date))`.